# expandable list view with checkbox for group and child

Tags: android, expandablelistview

[image]

I have no idea on expandable list view concept in android. Above is the image i want to create. When user clicks on it, it should expand with child having check box. Even the group should have check box. When i click on group check box, all the child check box should be selected. I checked other posts they are using it in activity. How to implement this in a dialog? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to implement this in a dialog?

You can create a `Dialog` using a `DialogFragment` and override `onCreateView()`. This allows you as much freedom with the `Dialog` UI as you have in any `Activity`, so the other SO posts you read will be very helpful there.

To get you started, see this [guide on dialogs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

Comment: @Harshit - you're welcome :) If this answer was what you were looking for you may accept it (small grey symbol below votes). If at a later point someone else has a better answer, you can always change the accepted answer.